# What could explain the bizarre discrepancy in the geometry between these two 3D maps?

Tags: geometry, google-maps, 3d, mapbox-gl-js, differences

GPS location: 33.67619789331771, -117.68029382324094

MapBox GL JS screenshot: [image]
Google Maps screenshot: [image]

What could explain this?

It should be noted that, for the places I actually know in real life, MapBox GL JS's geometry appears to be accurate. So it's not "completely messed up". But I spotted this while randomly looking at different areas, and it's probably *not* some unique thing.

Note: Even though they have in recent years rebuilt the left part with houses, it doesn't seem like they have changed the actual landscape of the road, which in theory could explain the difference.

Comment: I'd guess that MapBox GL JS uses a low resolution DEM (probably with some interpolation method to increase the original resolution) while Google Maps uses a high resolution DSM for this area.

Comment: Why downvote, though?

Comment: Dont ask me....

Comment: Isn't there also clear signs of large excavations beside the left-to-right road? The hill may have really disappeared.

Comment: It looks like the MapBox version is just an aerial image (ortho) that is draped over a surface model.  It looks like the Google version is maybe a composite of street view imagery (obliques) cast upon a surface model that includes building heights.